# Python and cgi output in the same html page

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi, return-value

From inside a web page I define short python code in a texarea field which should be run via cgi. I have no problem to create a new web page with the output of the external python run. What I like is instead the output below the textarea field in an iframe or whatever. But not as a new html page.

I have a html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<style>
  textarea {white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;}
</style>
<form action="/cgi-bin/getword3.py" method="post" >
<textarea name="py-code" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

*** the output of the cgi should appear here ***
    
</body>
</html>
```

my *not working* python cgi is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

if form.getlist('py-code'):
   text_content = form.getvalue('py-code')
else:
   text_content = "Not entered"

process = Popen(["python3", "-c", text_content], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

return stdout.decode())
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: You also have a stray, invalid `</br>` tag. (There is no such thing as `</br>`)